# how to import variable from while loop in different python program

Tags: python, variables, serialization, import, serial-communication

I have a python program named **communication.py** to receive data from Arduino as below:

```
    import serial

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=1)

    ser.reset_input_buffer()

    while True:

        if ser.in_waiting > 0:

            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()

            if (line == "0.0"):

                data = (0,0) 

            print(data)
```

the program can print variable values correctly
but
in another python named **print.py** program, I tried to export the variable named **data** in this way

```
from communication import data

print(data)
```

but that doesn't work because the python.py program doesn't recognize the variable named "data". Does this error have something to do with the while loop?

Comment: i perefer define a function and return your data as whatever you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: When import a module the whole code inside `if __name__ == 'main':` block is never executed